# How to compare two array test dsa das dsge a

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to go through 2 arrays and compare them and return true for the property approved.

Comment: `this.unApprovedUser.id` always returns `null` since `this.unApprovedUser` is an array, not an object

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this.unApprovedUser is an array of objects that have an id property

```
let users = this.allUsers.filter(obj => {
  return this.unApprovedUser.some(uau => uau.id === obj.userId);
});

users.forEach(u => u.approved = true);
```

Comment: okay but i need to set property approved to true

Comment: okay that’s very easy once you have the `users` array see edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to find if there is a matching id in `this.unApprovedUser` rather than just treat the array as an object.

```
let users = this.allUsers.filter(obj => {
  return this.unApprovedUser.find(element => element.id === obj.id);
});
```

edit: To also set all the filtered users to have `true` in `approved` key, add a map

```
let users = this.allUsers
    .filter(obj => this.unApprovedUser.find(element => element.id === obj.id))
    .map(user => (user.approved = true));
```

Comment: okay but i need to set property approved to true

Answer (score 0):

You could try this,

```
allUsers = allUsers.map(user=>{
 user.approved = unApprovedUsers.some(item=>item.id == user.userId);
 return user;})
```

this will update the return new array with the updated approved property.